# slider banner on android kotlin with photos 100% of the screen

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

****slider banner on android kotlin all i found was detectDragGestures does anyone have any better suggestions?****

slider banner with photos 100% of mobile phone screen

Comment: Could you explain better what you want to achieve? Is it something like ViewPager?

Comment: I have four images and I want to make a swipe gallery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Pager](https://github.com/google/accompanist/tree/main/pager) from the [accompanist library](https://github.com/google/accompanist).

You just need to add the dependency:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.8.1"
}
```

And then use it as the following:

```kotlin
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@Composable
fun ViewPagerScreen() {
    val images = listOf(
        R.drawable.image1,
        // include the other images here...
    )
    HorizontalPager(
        state = rememberPagerState(pageCount = images.size), 
        offscreenLimit = 2
    ) { page ->
        Image(
            painterResource(id = images[page]),
            null,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
    }
}
```

If you need to load images from web, you can use another accompanist library: [Coil](https://github.com/google/accompanist/blob/main/coil) or [Glide](https://github.com/google/accompanist/blob/main/glide).

Comment: I will test and send a feedback afterwards. I will use Coil for images Thanks

Comment: Great! Don't forget to accept the answer ;)